# Quantikz: Control gates are not connected by lines

Tags: quantikz

I am using quantikz library to draw a circuit diagram similar to the ones in this [research paper](https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2020-02-06-226/pdf/). I can see a gap in the wires after the 4th S gate on the 1st and 4th qubits. I have tried fiddling with the ampersands (&) but nothing seems to have worked. How do I force the lines to appear?

The output I get is this:
[image]

My latex code is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{quantikz} % for drawing Quantum Circuits

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{quantikz}
  \lstick{$q_0\  \ket{0}$} & &  \gate{S(0)} & \gate{S(12)} & \ctrl{1} &  \gate{S(0)} & \gate{S(12)} &  &\ctrl{3} & \meter{}  \\
  \lstick{$q_1 \ \ket{0}$} & &  \gate{S(3)} & \gate{S(15)} & \ctrl{} &  \gate{S(3)} & \gate{S(15)}   &   \ctrl{1} & \\
  \lstick{$q_2\  \ket{0}$} & &  \gate{S(6)} & \gate{S(18)} & \ctrl{1} &  \gate{S(6)} & \gate{S(18)} &   \ctrl{} & \\
  \lstick{$q_3 \ \ket{0}$} & &  \gate{S(9)} & \gate{S(21)} & \ctrl{} &  \gate{S(9)} & \gate{S(21)}  & & \ctrl{}   \\
\end{quantikz}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The argument of `\ctrl` must not be empty. Your `\ctrl{}` therefore result in several errors:

> ```
> Missing number, treated as zero.
> <to be read again> 
>                    \relax 
> l.15 \end
>          {quantikz}
> ```

Note: *You should never ignore errors!* Even if a PDF is generated, you are never sure, that the PDF is correct. And even if it seems to be correct, the next change can break it. After an error TeX only tries to find a simple syntactical workaround, mostly by ignoring code or adding mathmode or curly braces. TeX cannot not guarantee the semantic correctness of such workarounds. Often the workaround even results in another error and the workaround for this follow-up error may also result in other errors etc. So, if there is a problem, always start with correcting the first error.

IMHO all your `\ctrl{}` should be `\ctrl{0}`:

```latex
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{graphicx} % Not needed for the example
\usepackage{quantikz} % for drawing Quantum Circuits

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{quantikz}
  \lstick{$q_0\  \ket{0}$} & &  \gate{S(0)} & \gate{S(12)} & \ctrl{1} &  \gate{S(0)} & \gate{S(12)} &  &\ctrl{3} & \meter{}  \\
  \lstick{$q_1 \ \ket{0}$} & &  \gate{S(3)} & \gate{S(15)} &  \ctrl{0} &  \gate{S(3)} & \gate{S(15)}   &   \ctrl{1} & \\
  \lstick{$q_2\  \ket{0}$} & &  \gate{S(6)} & \gate{S(18)} & \ctrl{1} &  \gate{S(6)} & \gate{S(18)} & \ctrl{0}  & \\
  \lstick{$q_3 \ \ket{0}$} & &  \gate{S(9)} & \gate{S(21)} &  \ctrl{0} &  \gate{S(9)} & \gate{S(21)}  & & \ctrl{0}   \\
\end{quantikz}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But I don't know, if the resulting figure is correct:

[image: with lines at the end of row 2 and 3]

or you want, for example:

[image]

which is the result of (note the missing `&` at the end of the second and third row):

```latex
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{graphicx} % Not needed for the example
\usepackage{quantikz} % for drawing Quantum Circuits

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{quantikz}
  \lstick{$q_0\  \ket{0}$} & &  \gate{S(0)} & \gate{S(12)} & \ctrl{1} &  \gate{S(0)} & \gate{S(12)} &  &\ctrl{3} & \meter{}  \\
  \lstick{$q_1 \ \ket{0}$} & &  \gate{S(3)} & \gate{S(15)} &  \ctrl{0} &  \gate{S(3)} & \gate{S(15)}   &   \ctrl{1}  \\
  \lstick{$q_2\  \ket{0}$} & &  \gate{S(6)} & \gate{S(18)} & \ctrl{1} &  \gate{S(6)} & \gate{S(18)} & \ctrl{0}   \\
  \lstick{$q_3 \ \ket{0}$} & &  \gate{S(9)} & \gate{S(21)} &  \ctrl{0} &  \gate{S(9)} & \gate{S(21)}  & & \ctrl{0}   \\
\end{quantikz}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I'm using LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> with L3 programming layer <2023-11-09> (see the beginning of your `log` file) and the following file versions (see the end of the `log` file of the examples above:

```latex
 *File List*
 article.cls    2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
quantikz.sty    2023/05/24 typeset quantum circuit diagrams
    tikz.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
     pgf.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
  pgfrcs.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
graphicx.sty    2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
  pgfsys.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
  xcolor.sty    2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
mathcolor.ltx
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
  pgffor.sty    2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
 pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
pgfmath.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
   xargs.sty    2008/03/22 v1.1  extended macro definitions  (mpg)
 xkeyval.sty    2022/06/16 v2.9 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
  ifthen.sty    2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
 xstring.sty    2023/08/22 v1.86 String manipulations (CT)
  xparse.sty    2023-10-10 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2023-11-09 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-pdftex.def    2023-11-09 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
mathtools.sty    2022/06/29 v1.29 mathematical typesetting tools
    calc.sty    2023/07/08 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 mhsetup.sty    2021/03/18 v1.4 programming setup (MH)
 amsmath.sty    2023/05/13 v2.17o AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
 environ.sty    2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments
trimspaces.sty    2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

With old versions of `quantikz` you would also need to add `\phantomgate{…}` or `\hphantomgate` as a workaround to avoid gaps in the wires. For the last example above, this would be, e.g.:

```latex
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{quantikz} % for drawing Quantum Circuits

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{quantikz}
  \lstick{$q_0\  \ket{0}$} & &  \gate{S(0)} & \gate{S(12)} & \ctrl{1} &
  \gate{S(0)} & \gate{S(12)} & \hphantomgate{}  &\ctrl{3} & \meter{}  \\
  \lstick{$q_1 \ \ket{0}$} & &  \gate{S(3)} & \gate{S(15)} &  \ctrl{0} &  \gate{S(3)} & \gate{S(15)}   &   \ctrl{1}  \\
  \lstick{$q_2\  \ket{0}$} & &  \gate{S(6)} & \gate{S(18)} & \ctrl{1} &  \gate{S(6)} & \gate{S(18)} & \ctrl{0}   \\
  \lstick{$q_3 \ \ket{0}$} & &  \gate{S(9)} & \gate{S(21)} &  \ctrl{0} &
  \gate{S(9)} & \gate{S(21)}  & \hphantomgate{} & \ctrl{0}   \\
\end{quantikz}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The width of the argument of `\hphantomgate` is used for the width of the invisible gate. If you, e.g., would use `\hphantomgate{this is a very wide gate}` the horizontal lines will be longer than with the shown `\hphantomgate{}`. Due to a bug in older versions of `quantikz` the argument of `\hphantomgate` can also result in more vertical distance. This has been fixed meanwhile.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I used the code you provided, but I still get the same thing. 

Interestingly, I didn't get that error message either when I was writing that code. I got some other message like "missing }".

I am using Overleaf. Could this be because of that?

Comment: @VishwajeetOhal If you are using old package versions, you may need additional `\hphantomgate{}`. See my extended answer.